# Getting exception java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 , while generating excel file using java

Tags: java, excel, spring-mvc, jxl, excelbuilder.js

We are getting below exception in log during to generate excel file , we are using jxl version 2.6:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [webui] in context with path [/newui] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0] with root  causejava.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0at 
java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)at 
java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)at 
jxl.write.biff.WritableWorkbookImpl.getSheet(WritableWorkbookImpl.java:399)at jxl.write.biff.WritableWorkbookImpl.write(WritableWorkbookImpl.java:767)at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.document.AbstractJExcelView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractJExcelView.java:142)
```

Sample code to generate Excel file is (servlet snippet code) :

```
try {
    WritableWorkbook w = null;
    logger.info("ExcelBuilder Called");
    User loggedRcpt = (User)  request.getSession(true).getAttribute("user");
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    w = Workbook.createWorkbook(out);
    WritableFont wf = new WritableFont(WritableFont.ARIAL, 10, WritableFont.BOLD);
    WritableCellFormat cf = new WritableCellFormat(wf);
    cf.setAlignment(Alignment.LEFT);
    WritableCellFormat wc = new WritableCellFormat();
    cf.setAlignment(Alignment.LEFT);
    wc.setWrap(true);
    WritableFont writableFormat = new WritableFont(WritableFont.ARIAL, 9, WritableFont.NO_BOLD);
    writableFormat.setItalic(true);
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");


    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" +filename+".xls");
    WritableSheet sheet = w.createSheet(filename, 0);
    int rowNo = 1;
    Label Empid= new Label(0, 0, "Emp ID", cf);
    sheet.setColumnView(0, 40);
    sheet.addCell(Empid);
    Label forenameCol = new Label(1, 0, "Forename", cf);
    sheet.setColumnView(1, 40);
    sheet.addCell(forenameCol);

    Employee Emp= (Employee) iterator.next();
    Label employeeId = new Label(0, rowNo, Emp.getEmployeeId());
    sheet.addCell(employeeId);
    sheet.addCell(forename);
    Label surname = new Label(2, rowNo, Emp.getSurname());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error(e);
    }
    finally {
      try {
          if(w!=null){
            w.write();
            w.close();
          }
      } catch (Exception e) {
          sysout.error(e);
      }
    }
```

Please help us out to solve this exception.
Thank you.

Comment: Where is line 547?

Comment: Hi user3437460, we got this line number 547 in localhost.log of tomcat due to WritableWorkbookImpl class which is inside JXL jar(this jar is used to read and write excel sheet). so we are trying to understand why jxl jar is throwing this exception.

Comment: Hey, were you able to solve the issue? I am also consistently getting this error.